# Can't read from / write to SPI EEPROM

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, spi, eeprom

I'm currently trying to write to and read from an 25LC256-E EEPROM with my Arduino Uno via SPI. I've made a program which is supposed to do this, but I only get weird answers.

I'm sending in a Serial-string.
This string should start with 'w', 'r' or 'e', depending on what action I want to perform. The second character should be an int between 0 and 3 to determine witch PIN I should use as slave (currently I'm using only 1 slave, so the int should always be 0).
The rest of the string gets written to the EEPROM, one byte/character at the time.

What am I missing?

CODE:

```
    #include <SPI.h>

    #define WREN  6
    #define WRDI  4
    #define RDSR  5
    #define WRSR  1
    #define READ  3
    #define WRITE 2

    // Multiple slaves for future project
    const int CHANNELS[4] = {10, 8, 7, 4};
    String readResult;

    void setup() {

      Serial.begin(9600);
      channelSetup(); // Set all slave pins in CHANNELS to OUTPUT and HIGH

      SPI.begin();
      SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
      SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
      SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);

    }

    void loop() {

      Serial.println("START");

      while(!Serial.available());
      delay(20);

      // Get all available bytes/characters
      String serialInput = getSerialStream(Serial.available());

      // Second character in serialInput is an int between 0 and 3
      int channel = makeValidChannel(serialInput[1]);

      // "channel" must be between 0 and 3
      // to be able to point to CHANNELS
      if (channel >= 0 && channel <= 3) {

        // First character decides what to do
        switch (serialInput[0]) {

          case 'w':
            writeToChannel(channel, serialInput.substring(2));
            break;

          case 'r':
            readResult = "EMPTY";
            readResult = readFromChannel(channel);
            Serial.print("Result: ");
            Serial.println(readResult);
            break;

          case 'e':
            overWriteEEPROM(channel);
            break;

          default:
            Serial.println("INVALID FIRST OPERATION");

        }

      }

      else
        Serial.print("INVALID CHANNEL: ");
        Serial.println(channel);

    }

    void channelSetup() {

      for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(CHANNELS); i++) {

        pinMode(CHANNELS[i], OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(CHANNELS[i], HIGH);

      }

    }

    String getSerialStream(int numOfChars) {

      char serialStream[numOfChars + 1];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < numOfChars; i++) {

        serialStream[i] = char(Serial.read());
        delay(5);

      }

      serialStream[i] = '\0';
      return String(serialStream);

    }

    int makeValidChannel(char chIn) {

      int channel = chIn - '0';
      //channel -= 48;

      if (channel >= 0 && channel <= 3)
        return channel;
      else
        return -1;

    }

    void writeToChannel(int channel, String message) {

      int slaveselect = CHANNELS[channel];
      int i;

      // Write enabled
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
      SPI.transfer(WREN);
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
      delay(5);

      // Disable Write Protection
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
      SPI.transfer(WRSR);
      SPI.transfer(0);
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
      delay(5);

      for (i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {

        digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(WRITE);
        SPI.transfer(0);
        SPI.transfer(i);
        SPI.transfer(message[i]);
        digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
        delay(5);

      }

      // When writing of "message" is done,
      // add a 0-byte as terminating character
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
      SPI.transfer(WRITE);
      SPI.transfer(0);
      SPI.transfer(i);
      SPI.transfer(0x00);
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
      delay(5);


      // Enable Write Protection
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
      SPI.transfer(WRSR);
      SPI.transfer(3);
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
      delay(5);

      // Write Disabled
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
      SPI.transfer(WRDI);
      digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
      delay(5);

    }

    String readFromChannel(int channel) {

      Serial.println("Reading started");

      int slaveselect = CHANNELS[channel];
      char outputArr[64];
      int i = 0;

      while (true) {

        digitalWrite(slaveselect, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(READ);
        SPI.transfer(0);
        SPI.transfer(i);
        outputArr[i] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
        digitalWrite(slaveselect, HIGH);
        delay(5);

        if (outputArr[i] == 0x00 || i >= 64) {

          outputArr[i] = '\0';
          return String(outputArr);  

                }

        else
          i++;

      }

    }

    void overWriteEEPROM(int channel) {

      char zeroArr[64];
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

        zeroArr[i] = 0;

      }

      writeToChannel(channel, String(zeroArr))

    }
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue, but the `else` part of your if statement in the loop is missing opening and closing curly brackets....

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin : No, but thanks for noticing. It's just a minor bug that causes `Serial.println(channel);` to run regardless of if/else.

Comment: "but I only get weird answers". That's kind of vague, could you give us some sample outputs?

Comment: @Gerben : I tested some more, and I think I found out what the "weird answers" were: I filled the first 8 adressfields of my EEPROM (using working demo code) with int values ranging from 59 and upwards, and when I tried reading the values later they printed out in ASCII. I.E., "59" became ";".

Comment: @DoTheGenes great work. So it's solved then!

Comment: @Gerben : Sort of. I've solved the mystery of what the weird answers was, but the `readFromChannel()` will not stop when the string i wrote to the EEPROM is read out, it just continues to read through all addresses.
Basically, the only reason it stops is because I put the `i >= 64`-condition in the `if`-statement. The `null`-terminator will not work as intended.

Comment: That's weird. Try adding `Serial.print(outputArr[i], BIN)` to see the individual bits being read. Check if there is indeed a `0x00` present.